# Argument of type '{ from: string; to: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Date'. in enabling dates in flatpickr

Tags: angular, typescript, web, flatpickr

I am trying to enable dates in flatpickr calender which is integrated with angular. So when I am trying to push enable date object to enable config option of flatpickr then I am getting `Argument of type '{ from: string; to: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Date'.`

Here is the code for config. of flatpickr:-

```
this.exampleOptions = {
  dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
  minDate: "today",
  maxDate: "",
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
    // console.log('selected date is ', selectedDates);
    console.log('latest selected dates ', dateStr);
    this.selectedDate = selectedDates;
    this.dateSelected = selectedDates;
    console.log('this.dateSelected ', this.dateSelected);
    console.log('this.selectedDate ', this.selectedDates);
  }
};
```

In a function I am using that config object to enable dates:-

```
allAboutDateAndTime(){
  if (this.experienceData.dateRangeList != null && this.experienceData.dateRangeList != undefined && this.experienceData.dateRangeList.length > 0) {
  this.experienceData.dateRangeList.forEach((date: DateRange) => {
    const from = date.startDate.toString();
    const to = date.endDate.toString();
    const enable = {
      from: from,
      to: to
    };
    this.exampleOptions.enable.push(enable); // GETTING ERROR HERE
  });
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Argument of type '{ from: string; to: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Date'. Type '{ from: string; to: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 38 more
```

I am expecting it to enable the assigned dates as given in flatpickr [documentaion](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/)

Answer (score 1):

As you're using with Angular, I guess you must be using [ng2-flatpickr](https://github.com/mezoistvan/ng2-flatpickr) i guess. And I tried downloading their Javascript package[flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) and [ng2-flatpickr](https://github.com/mezoistvan/ng2-flatpickr) and I came to know that their angular package doesn't have all the features that JS package has!

As per their JS package, that **enable** property should be the type of what following image shows...

[image]

As per their Angular package, **enable** property should be in the type of...

[image]

So probably, you can't use angular package to achieve what u need. Either you should try to use JS package in your angular project, or you have to raise an issue in their Angular package github repo.

[Bug - enable option should support function #57](https://github.com/mezoistvan/ng2-flatpickr/issues/57)

There's already an issue related to that to ask them to make that **enable** property should accept the function as JS package does!

So you can raise your issue there! Or If you want to achieve it somehow in your project, try with their JS package!

Comment: Great @Kartik, I did not think about it. You have gone into its depth.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the same console.log(this.experienceData) to check what type of object it is and what properties and methods it has? Maybe the enable array is never assigned itself and you have to initialize it before usage to an empty one?

As it seems you are trying to assign to an existing property a propertie of a different type or push to an array which does not hold this type of objects you are trying to introduce.

Try this:

this.exampleOptions.enable= [{
            from: "2025-04-01",
            to: "2025-05-01"
        }]

If it still errors then there something in your code that is incorrectly assigning type or not initializing the array in the first place.

**UPDATE**

Try

```
this.exampleOptions = {
  dateFormat: "d.m.Y",
  minDate: "today",
  maxDate: "",
  enable: ["2015-12-01"]
  onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr) {
    // console.log('selected date is ', selectedDates);
    console.log('latest selected dates ', dateStr);
    this.selectedDate = selectedDates;
    this.dateSelected = selectedDates;
    console.log('this.dateSelected ', this.dateSelected);
    console.log('this.selectedDate ', this.selectedDates);
  }
};
```

Try to initialize the object together with the enable array and some random value that fits the format see if it works then. Otherwise, try to assign proper types to every variable.

Comment: I am still getting same error. My motive is to enable all the dates that coming from server that is ```this.experienceData.dateRangeList``` array . Here is the response from server ```dateRangeList: Array(59)
0: {startDate: "03-04-2019", endDate: "03-04-2019"}
1: {startDate: "04-04-2019", endDate: "04-04-2019"}
2: {startDate: "05-04-2019", endDate: "05-04-2019"}
3: {startDate: "07-04-2019", endDate: "07-04-2019"}
4: {startDate: "06-04-2019", endDate: "06-04-2019"}
5: {startDate: "08-04-2019", endDate: "08-04-2019"}
6: {startDate: "16-04-2019", endDate: "16-04-2019"}```

Comment: So I am iterating over the dateRangeList array and inside that loop assigning ```this.exampleOptions.enable = [ {from: element.startDate, to: element.endDate}]``` but I am getting the same error . How can I fix that ?

Comment: yeah @vsarunov, it is working like you mentioned above, but I want to enable the dates coming from server in array format on loading the page(i.e ngOnInit), so when I try to use ```this.exampleOptions.enable.push(date.startDate)``` over each iteration then its not working, Can you please help to fix this ?

Comment: Try creating your array before you initialize the this.exampleOptions and then assign it to enable when initialized.